# Going back page causes multiple renders in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I am building an application with nextjs and supabase. I have a few pages where the structures are

```
const SomePage = async () => {
  const user = await supabase.auth.getUser()

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <SomeClientSidePage user={user} />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

and inside SomeClientSidePage, I am routing to a different page on some actions.

When I initially load the page, everything is fine. However, when I do router.back after doing some actions, server side component is rendering multiple times.

I tested this by adding a logging statement in SomePage by doing

```
const SomePage = async () => {
  const user = await supabase.auth.getUser()

  console.log('here')
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <SomeClientSidePage user={user} />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

and I noticed that here is being printed out over 20 times! On initial page load, here is printed out just once.

And when 'here' is printed over certain threshold (probably like 35-40 times), I am getting

```
Uncaught Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.
```

Once I get rid of the `const user = await supabase.auth.getUser()` and async, I notice that this issue disappears.

As I am learning more about nextjs, what is the cause and how can I fix it?

Comment: I also notice that more routing changes cause more renders in general

Comment: Could you please reproduce your problem in codesandbox and share the link?